# SQL : Needs help in joins in Sql Server

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have following tables , schemas are

---

### Table: Member

```
Id        // PK Int Auto Increment
MemberID
MembershipType        // Holds MemberShipMaster types 1/2/3 for Prem, Corp or Free
RegisteredCountry     // FK of CountryMaster table
RegisteredState       // FK of States Table
RegisteredCity        // FK of Districts table
PostalCountry         // FK of CountryMaster table
PostalState           // FK of States Table
PostalCity            // FK of Districts table
```

**Please note : Postal and Registered address could be different (its logical...)**

---

### Table : CountryMaster

```
Id        // PK , int auto increment
Country   // Name of Country
```

---

### Table : MemberShipMaster

```
Id               // PK int auto increment
Type             // Type Id int   , 1,2,3 respectively for Prem, Corp and Free
TypeName          // Membership Type Name e.g. Premium, Corporate, Free
```

---

### Tbale : Cities

```
Id,         // PK int auto increment
Name       
StateId     // FK, PK of states table
```

---

### Table : States

```
Id   // PK int auto increment
Name           
CountryId // FK , PK of COuntry
```

Below is my query

```
SELECT Id , MemberID, MembershipType, Districts.Name as RegisteredCity,
States.Name as RegisteredState,CountryMaster.Country as RegisteredCountry,
Districts.Name as PostalCity,States.Name as PostalState, CountryMaster.Country as PostalCountry 
FROM   dbo.JFPMembers RIGHT  JOIN MemberShipMaster ON MemberShipMaster.Id= dbo.JFPMembers.MembershipType  
LEFT  JOIN  Districts ON dbo.JFPMembers.PostalCity = Districts.Id OR  Districts.Id =JFPMembers.RegisteredCity
LEFT  JOIN  States ON States.Id = dbo.JFPMembers.RegisteredState OR States.Id = dbo.JFPMembers.PostalState
LEFT  JOIN CountryMaster ON CountryMaster.Id = dbo.JFPMembers.RegisteredCountry and CountryMaster.Id = dbo.JFPMembers.postalCountry
Where Id= @id
```

My Expected Output :

**Appropriate name of city, state or country in the fields below as per the id's saved in the column. But Instead of that I am getting  null values in the desired columns**. I have confirmed that the two values exists in the database for working with joins.

Districts.Name as RegisteredCity,States.Name as RegisteredState,CountryMaster.Country as RegisteredCountry,Districts.Name as PostalCity,States.Name as PostalState,,CountryMaster.Country as PostalCountry

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are trying to join with two different conditions.  Instead join to your lookup tables twice.  Like this:

```
SELECT Id , MemberID, MembershipType, RegDistricts.Name as RegisteredCity,
    RegStates.Name as RegisteredState, RegCountryMaster.Country as RegisteredCountry,
    PostalDistricts.Name as PostalCity, PostalStates.Name as PostalState, 
    PostalCountryMaster.Country as PostalCountry 
FROM dbo.JFPMembers 
LEFT JOIN MemberShipMaster 
    ON MemberShipMaster.Id = dbo.JFPMembers.MembershipType  
LEFT JOIN Districts RegDistricts
    ON RegDistricts.Id = JFPMembers.RegisteredCity
LEFT JOIN Districts  PostalDistricts
    ON dbo.JFPMembers.PostalCity = PostalDistricts.Id 
LEFT JOIN States RegStates
    ON RegStates.Id = dbo.JFPMembers.RegisteredState 
LEFT JOIN States PostalStates
    ON PostalStates.Id = dbo.JFPMembers.PostalState
LEFT JOIN CountryMaster RegCountryMaster
    ON RegCountryMaster.Id = dbo.JFPMembers.RegisteredCountry 
LEFT JOIN CountryMaster PostalCountryMaster
    ON PostalCountryMaster.Id = dbo.JFPMembers.postalCountry
Where Id= @id
```

Answer (score 1):

Postal needs its joins to the respective country, state and city tables on its own via separate aliases... Same with Registered...

```
SELECT 
      M.Id, 
      M.MemberID, 
      M.MembershipType, 
      MM.TypeName as MembershipTypeName,
      RegCountryAlias.Country as RegisteredCountry,
      RegStatesAlias.Name as RegisteredState,
      RegCitiesAlias.Name as RegisteredCity,
      PostalCountryAlias.Country as PostalCountry,
      PostalStatesAlias.Name as PostalState,
      PostalCitiesAlias.Name as PostalCity
   FROM   
      JFPMembers M
         JOIN MemberShipMaster MM
            ON M.MembershipType = MemberShipMaster.Id

         JOIN CountryMaster as RegCountryAlias
            ON M.RegisteredCountry = RegCountryAlias.ID
         JOIN States as RegStatesAlias
            ON M.RegisteredState = RegStatesAlias.ID
         JOIN Cities as RegCitiesAlias
            ON M.RegisteredCity = RegCitiesAlias.ID

         JOIN CountryMaster as PostalCountryAlias
            ON M.PostalCountry = PostalCountryAlias.ID
         JOIN States as PostalStatesAlias
            ON M.PostalState = PostalStatesAlias.ID
         JOIN Cities as PostalCitiesAlias
            ON M.PostalCity = PostalCitiesAlias.ID
   WHERE
      M.ID = @id
```

As Kenneth pointed out about possible NULLs if any column didn't specifically find a match in the corresponding joined table, it would not return a record.  Therefore, you would probably change the JOINs to LEFT JOINs.  Additionally, you mentioned a "Districts" table, but did not provide, but DID provide your "Cities" table which is what I used as the basis of the joins.

Comment: Unless the id columns are NOT NULL you should probably leave the JOINs as LEFT OUTER JOINs.

Comment: @KennethFisher, I would agree with you on that for the nulls... however it appears the poster is not expecting nulls and the record entry would have all elements to properly join for Registered AND Postal columns.

Comment: I always like the LEFT OUTER JOINs unless the columns are explicitly NOT NULL just in case.  It's a lot easier to debug a null value in a result set than a missing row.  Of course this particular question is from late last year.  I really hope they already found an answer :)

Comment: @KennethFisher, I do too in most cases, but it also is on the developer to help ensure good data too.

Answer (score 0):

> LEFT  JOIN CountryMaster ON CountryMaster.Id = dbo.JFPMembers.RegisteredCountry and CountryMaster.Id = dbo.JFPMembers.postalCountry

Did you mean `and` or `or`?

Comment: Well, `and` doesn't look like it would work, unless you want the `RegisteredCountry` to equal the `postalCountry`.

Comment: As an aside, I'm not sure if you need to store Country, State and City in the Member table. City has a FK to State and State has an FK to Country.